# How many attacks would be in a full-attack with this Ratfolk Monk/Ninja?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monk, natural-weapon

I've tried doing some research on this, and I'm still confused on the rules. By RAW, how many attacks could I get as a full-attack with this guy?

Steve the Testrat, 4 Flowing Monk/16 Ninja (BAB+15), Tailblade, Ring of Rat Fangs

(Relevant) Feats: Sharpclaw, Improved Unarmed Strike, ??Two-Weapon Fighting (+ Improved, + Greater)

I've heard conflicting information about it, but as far as I can piece together, what would happen is, that Steve can use Flurry of Blows from his monk levels, but NOT two-weapon fighting, and his attack layout would look like:

US(primary)/US(iterative)/US(iterative)/US(Flurry)/Claw/Claw/Bite/Tailblade

He would incur a -2 penalty across ALL of his attacks for Flurrying, but that would be reduced to -1 on his unarmed strikes, because his BAB from his monk levels would rise from +3 to +4. All of his natural attacks would be 'secondary' attacks.

Is all of this correct? Or am I missing something?

Also, a related question, would a tailblade/ring of rat fangs count for the natural attacks required to take Multiattack?

(This is my first question by the way, hope I asked this right.)

Comment: Treat two weapon fighting AND unarmed strike as the exact same thing. Your last 4 attacks would incur a -5 penalty because they would now be considered secondary natural attacks. (Give me a sec I'm piecing it together) Are you using unarmed strikes in the form of kicks?

Comment: Also, do not confuse the monk bab with the penalty, you will incur the -2 penalty on everything regardless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are considered to have the two weapon fighting feat when using a flurry of blows maneuver with some exceptions. When using a flurry of blows, all attacks under the flurry are at full strength modifier and your base attack bonus in monk levels is replaced with your level in monk (3 BAB from monk becomes 4 BAB). Normally a monk would hit level 8 and not need Improved TWF, or hit 15 and not need Greater, but because you are level 4, you can use the Improved and Greater.

This means that when you use a flurry of blows, you should have a BAB of 16 -> 4 attacks. In addition, because you only have 4 levels of monk, Improved TWF and Greater TWF will stack however they will only use .5 str (I am second guessing myself on this one, I think you still get to apply full strength because of flurry)

7 Attacks:

BAB +16(-2) / FOB +16 (-2) / BAB +11(-2) / Improved TWF +11(-2) / BAB +6(-2) / Greater TWF +6(-2) / BAB +1(-2)

> A monk cannot use any weapon other than an unarmed strike or a special monk weapon as part of a flurry of blows. A monk with natural weapons cannot use such weapons as part of a flurry of blows, nor can he make natural attacks in addition to his flurry of blows attacks.

To answer your second question you have Claw/Claw/Bite = 3 natural attacks for the multi attack feat.

Comment: I cannot believe I missed that section about not combining FoB with Natural Attacks... So am I right in that it comes down to either going full FoB, and getting 7 attacks, or going iteratively with 3 unarmed strikes + the 4 natural attacks, with the latter strategy being a loss of attack/damage across all of its attacks?

Comment: @Redler You can combine the natural attacks with two weapon fighting however, the problem is that the feats specify an off hand attack, so you would only be able to apply your bite and tail attacks because your claw limbs would have been used

Comment: @Redler They did this because flurry of blows is made with unarmed attacks and you could technically perform the flurry of blows with your feet, leaving your other limbs open for natural attacks. Instead now, you will do two weapon fighting for a total of 8 attacks (Your base attack bonus is back down to 15), except at .5 strength on all the of-hand attacks.

Comment: @Redler Final: 8 attacks -  BAB +15 (-2) / TWF +15 (-2) / BAB +10 (-2) / ITWF +10 (-2) / BAB +5 (-2) / GTWF +5 (-2) / Bite +15 (-7) / Tail +15 (-7)

Comment: @Redler you have both options available, it is up to you. The FoB path will leave you with higher hits and more damage modifiers. TWF will give you more attacks. The payoff is up to you. I do not know what other feats you have, but if you have power attack for example, it would be better to use FoB (full strength from fob means full strength from pa)

Comment: @Redler One last thing, you are a monk at level 4, you get a ki pool that you can use to add an additional attack: Make one additional attack at his highest attack bonus when making a flurry of blows attack. So you could technically get 8 attacks with FoB too.